# no water in house

Tags: plumbing

In the past month I had some plumbing work done in the bathrooms. Both bathrooms had new fixtures put in. My house was built in 1953. The toilet in the main bath started making loud noises when flushed. Then the water in the entire house stopping working. I called a plumber on a Sunday and paid a bunch of money for that too, and the water came back on before he got there. He said I needed a new intake valve and came back and replaced it.

Last weekend the toilet make the loud noise again, and the water again stopped working in the whole house. The next day, before I called the plumber, the water came back on. Anybody have a clue what would cause this. I am not sure if the loud noises from the toilet are related to the water shutting off but it happened twice so I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps your pressure regulator valve has a problem, or perhaps your main valve has a failed seal which could flap closed.

Answer (score 4):

Kit - The noises from the toilet flush and the water shutdown could be coincidental but probably are related. The noise could be due to changing water pressure along with air in the line caused by a disruption in the water supply. This could be due to a faulty pressure regulator valve but could have other causes. You don't mention whether you are on city water or a well. I've seen instances where the water folks have done line repairs without notifying residents. Check with your water company and find out if any lines were being serviced in your area. I've known it to happen. If you're on a well it could be a faulty pump working intermittently.

Answer (score 1):

Totally going on a limb here, but.. a house built in that era could have some kind of iron piping (black pipe, galvanized pipe, etc). Iron piping can and will rust on the inside. It could also have mineral deposits on the inside.

It might be that the recent plumbing work caused some rust or scale to dislodge from the inside wall of the pipe and that debris is now working its way through your plumbing. A larger piece might get stuck along the way and then collect smaller pieces until finally the flow is blocked. It's not unlike logs, limbs, and grasses blocking a culvert and causing a canal to overflow.

You could try letting the water run at various taps for an extended period (30 minutes, for example). Watch the flow to see if any visible particles come out. Note that kitchen and bathroom sink faucets often have aerators installed right where the water comes out. You'd want to remove that so it wouldn't get clogged. Likewise for shower heads -- remove the head or run water through the bath filler instead.